# Remove leftBarButtonItem Background

Tags: objective-c

How to remove leftBarButtonItem blue background?
I tried `style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` but had no result.

Code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController action:@selector(openMenu) ];
```

[image]

Comment: once check your image is with what color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    UIButton *tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tempButton setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 1, 34, 34)]; // your Home Button Image width and height.
    [tempButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempButton]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The in your case `UINavigationController` is doing some additional styling when managing it's navigationBar and the `UIBarButtonItems` in it. So setting the style to plain will not behave the same as it does when working with a `UIToolbar`.

What you need is a custom view, something like...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
barButtonItem.target = self;
barButtonItem.action = @selector(openMenu);
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

Also, you will probably want `target` to set to `self` not `self.navigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with iOS 5+ there is another way that doesn't involve custom views. With the UIAppearance additions, you can use

```
UIImage * emptyImage() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, 1));
    UIImage * emptyImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return emptyImage;
}

UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith...];
[item setBackgroundImage:emptyImage() forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
```

and if this is an app-wide style, just do

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:emptyImage() forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

once in your AppDelegate and you won't even need to fuss with individual instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30, 40)];    
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn]];
```

This Will work please try....